# Looking for sort drop down list in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nstaggedpointerstring

I'm looking for sort my dropdown list into ascending order.

```
let set = NSSet(array: arrTemp as! [Any])
let arrNewPredicated = set.allObjects as NSArray
arrAllArrayCode = NSMutableArray (array: arrNewPredicated)
```

I have 17 elements that looks like this

```
[0]=(NSTaggedPointerString*)"AAA"
[1]=(NSTaggedPointerString*)"CCC"
[2]=(NSTaggedPointerString*)"BBB"
```

I would like to order them by ascending order.

Comment: You should drop the NS prefix when coding in Swift. Use Set instead of NSSet, Array instead of NSArray/NSMutableArray and String instead of NSString/NSTaggedPointerString

Answer (score 1):

I supposed `arrTemp` is an array of Strings so:

first of all you're using Swift so as **LeoDabus** suggests drop `NS` prefix. Than build your set:

```
let arrayOfStrings = ["beta", "omega", "alpha", "teta"]
let set = Set<String>(arrayOfStrings)
```

then just sort it:

```
let sorted = set.sorted()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array of `sortable elements`:

```
let arrTemp = ["AAA", "CCC", "BBB"]
let set = Set(arrTemp)
let arrNewPredicated = set.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    return str1 < str2
    // or use
    // return str2 < str1
}
```

Comment: I got the error message : Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Any' operands

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct line of code for my issues. 
If that can help someone..

```
let set = NSSet(array: arrTemp as! [Any])
let arrNewPredicated = set.allObjects as NSArray
let sortarray = arrNewPredicated.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "", ascending: true)])  as NSArray
```